# UIs not Displaying?

Tags: java

I was trying to implement suggestions of using layouts, not using JLayeredPane and having a more organized and structure coding in terms of variables. It took a while to recode my whole simple chat system and went from using a JScrollPane focused system to JList. However, for some reason, nothing in the "UIVisuals" displays at all?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ChatUI {
    private JTextField chat_input = new JTextField(8);
    private JPanel inner_background = new JPanel();
    private JList<String> chatList; // Use JList for chat display
    private DefaultListModel<String> chatModel; // Model to store chat data

    // Add a method to update the chat display
    public void updateChatDisplay(String message) {
        chatModel.addElement(message);
    }

    public void createScrollingList(JPanel i_bg) {
        // Other settings for the inner background panel
        i_bg.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.decode("#111214"), 2, true));
        i_bg.setLayout(new BoxLayout(i_bg, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        
        chatModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
        chatList = new JList<>(chatModel);
        
        // Set properties for the chatList
        chatList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION); // You can change this based on your requirements
        chatList.setBackground(Color.decode("#111214")); // Background color
        chatList.setForeground(Color.WHITE); // Text color
        chatList.setFont(new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.BOLD, 15)); // Font
        
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(chatList);
        sp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(330, 450));
        
        // Auto-scrolls down
        sp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        sp.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        
        // Set the background color of the scroll pane and its viewport
        sp.setBackground(Color.decode("#111214"));
        sp.getViewport().setBackground(Color.decode("#111214"));
        
        i_bg.add(sp); // Add the scroll pane to the inner background
        
        // Ensure the layout is updated
        i_bg.revalidate();
        i_bg.repaint();
    }

    static void UIVisuals(JFrame frame, JList<String> cl, JTextField cp) {
        ChatUI chatUI = new ChatUI();

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // Left frame
        JPanel topBackground = new JPanel();
        topBackground.setBackground(Color.decode("#62D0F6"));
        topBackground.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 80));

        // Right frame
        JPanel rightFrame = new JPanel();
        rightFrame.setBackground(Color.decode("#9B90B2"));
        rightFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 20));

        // User_Icon
        ImageIcon userIcon = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/pokec/OneDrive/Pictures/user_java_icon.png");
        JLabel userLabel = new JLabel(userIcon);

        // Emoji Button
        ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\pokec\\OneDrive\\Pictures\\gift_icon.png");
        JButton gift_button = new JButton(imageIcon);

        // Make button transparent
        gift_button.setOpaque(false);
        gift_button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        gift_button.setBorderPainted(false);

        // Texting Panel
        cp.setBackground(Color.decode("#383A40"));
        cp.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        cp.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.decode("#4B4D54"), 1, true));
        cp.setFont(new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.BOLD, 15));

        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        bottomPanel.add(cp, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Add components to mainPanel
        mainPanel.add(topBackground, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainPanel.add(rightFrame, BorderLayout.EAST);
        mainPanel.add(userLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        mainPanel.add(gift_button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        mainPanel.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // Event Listeners
        EventListeners eventListeners = new EventListeners(gift_button, cp, cl);
        cp.addActionListener(eventListeners);
        gift_button.addActionListener(eventListeners);

        chatUI.createScrollingList(chatUI.inner_background); // Pass chatList as an argument

        // Set the main panel as the content pane for the frame
        frame.setContentPane(mainPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class ChatSystem {   
    private GlobalVariables gV = new GlobalVariables();

    private JTextArea textArea = gV.getTextArea();
    private JFrame frame = gV.getFrame();
    private JTextField chat_input = gV.getChatInput();
    private JList<String> chatList = gV.getChatList();

    public static void createScrollingFrame(JFrame frame, JTextField cp, JList<String> cl) {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // UI Labels
        JLabel client = new JLabel();
        Font f3 = new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.BOLD, 35);
        client.setFont(f3);
        client.setText("Mee6 | BOT");
        client.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(); 
        topPanel.setOpaque(false);
        topPanel.add(client);
        
        frame.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH); 

        // Create everything else
        ChatUI.UIVisuals(frame, cl, cp);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            ChatSystem chat = new ChatSystem();

            chat.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            chat.frame.setVisible(true);
            chat.frame.setBackground(Color.decode("#313338"));
            chat.frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(380, 900)); 
            chat.frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(395, 1000));

            createScrollingFrame(chat.frame, chat.chat_input, chat.chatList);
   
    }
}
```

```
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class GlobalVariables {
    private JTextField chat_input = new JTextField(8);
    private JPanel inner_background = new JPanel();
    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(50, 2);
    private JList<String> chatList; // Use JList for chat display
    private DefaultListModel<String> chatModel; // Model to store chat data
    
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("ChatBot");
    private JFrame chatPanel = new JFrame();
    private JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();

    //getters
    public JTextField getChatInput() {
        return chat_input;
    }
    public JPanel getInnerBackground() {
        return inner_background;
    }
    public JTextArea getTextArea() {
        return textArea;
    }
    public JList getChatList() {
        return chatList;
    }

    public JFrame getFrame() {
        return frame;
    }

    public JFrame getChatPanel() {
        return chatPanel;
    }

    public JLayeredPane getLayeredPane() {
        return layeredPane;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's still messy code . I have not run it, but noted a couple of things. Try to move your call to setVisible() last, so all you gui are done before. Also from the main method create the gui in the event thread, by using SwingUtilities.invokeLatet()

Comment: Glad that you are trying to make changes but I still see many problems. There is no need for a GlobalVariables class. You should not be using all those static methods. I still see no need for the layered pane. I suggested you start by reading the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html). The "ListDemo" will provide a simple structure to build on. It show how to create the GUI on the Event Dispatch Thread and how to create the frame and then just add your "application panel" to the frame.

Comment: You should NOT be passing the frame reference around to your application.  So start with a frame with a couple of components and get it working then add more components and retest. Don't attempt to write the entire application before testing. One point, you can't add multiple components to the same BorderLayout area. I note that you try to add two components to the SOUTH. Instead you need to create a panel. Add the components to the panel and then add the panel to the SOUTH.